# Rails Stripe integration appears function on my end, but not on Stripe dashboard

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I have the following controller code for Books and Charges. Charges are nested within Books like so

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :hugs do
    resources :charges
  end
end
```

Books Controller

```
class BooksController < ApplicationController

    def index
        @books = Book.all
    end

    def create
    end

    def show
        @book = Book.find(params[:id])
    end
end
```

Charges Controller

```
class ChargesController < ApplicationController
    def create
        @book = Book.find(params[:book_id])


        customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
            :email => 'example@stripe.com',
            :card  => params[:stripeToken]
        )

        charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
            :customer    => customer.id,
            :amount      => @book.price,
            :description => 'Rails Stripe customer',
            :currency    => 'usd'
        )

        rescue Stripe::CardError => e
            flash[:error] = e.message
            redirect_to hugs_path
    end
end
```

I manually created all my Book objects within the console, so I don't have a new method for Book controller.

Right now at each Book show page, I have a Stripe button for payment. The payment seems to be working on my end, but when I check the dashboard, no payments were received.

The guide is taken from [here](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/guides/rails)

What might I be doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you check the activity log in the dashboard? Are there any event at all? Are you using it in the test mode?

Comment: Yes I am indeed using the test mode. In the log itself, it does show that the API call went through, so I am really confused as to what's happening here.

Comment: the log shows /v1/charges 200?

Comment: The log shows
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"some_token", "stripeToken"=>"some_other_token", "stripeTokenType"=>"card", "stripeEmail"=>"random@gmail.com"}.
Complete 200 OK

Comment: @user3277633 I think Matthew was referring to stripe logs, in your stripe dashboard: https://dashboard.stripe.com/logs

Comment: Ah Yes, Sorry I just realized this. In my dashboard, i am only receiving v1/tokens. No v1/customers or v1/charges. They did appear when I copied the guide as it is. What does the missing of customers and charges mean??

Answer (score 0):

you should have your publishable key in your view:

```
  <head>

    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script>
   <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico|Princess+Sofia' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
   <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Julius+Sans+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag  'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

  <!-- The required Stripe lib -->


  <!-- jQuery is used only for this example; it isn't required to use Stripe -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    // This identifies your website in the createToken call below
    Stripe.setPublishableKey('<%='pk_test_KfCg1YmVXwBYyEdPEWnfibF8'%>');

    var stripeResponseHandler = function(status, response) {
      var $form = $('#payment-form');

      if (response.error) {
        // Show the errors on the form
        $form.find('.payment-errors').text(response.error.message);
        $form.find('button').prop('disabled', false);
      } else {
        // token 
        var token = response.id;
        // Insert token into the form 
        $form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="stripeToken" />').val(token));
        // re-submit
        $form.get(0).submit();
      }
    };

    jQuery(function($) {
      $('#payment-form').submit(function(e) {
        var $form = $(this);

        // Disable the submit button to prevent repeated clicks
        $form.find('button').prop('disabled', true);

        //create the token before it hits the controller
        Stripe.card.createToken({
            number: $('.card-number').val(),
            cvc: $('.card-cvc').val(),
            exp_month: $('.card-expiry-month').val(),
            exp_year: $('.card-expiry-year').val()}, stripeResponseHandler);

        // Prevent the form from submitting with the default action
        return false;
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>
    //code for form goes down here //
```

you also need to make sure to have the gem installed (i assume you do, but thought it worth mentioning).

You also 'may' need to restart you server  and set your your environmental variables in terminal. You do it in one step: `MY_KEY=sk_jasahhfu084374ksk_or_whatever rails s`

Comment: Hi, not sure if this matters, but I followed with the guide and have the following `Stripe.api_key = Rails.configuration.stripe[:secret_key]` within my `config/initializer`, so the API key should be set up already

Comment: Read step 1 and 2 of custom use forms here: https://stripe.com/docs/tutorials/forms  and you will see you need not only a link to stripe in the head of your form, but also your publishable key, and the necessary jQuery to create a token and grab info from the form. Also i assume you have done this, but you need to that the stripe gem installed. Lastly, you are correct about it the secret_key not needing to be in the controller but the rest you do need

Comment: I have updated my answer to include the entire head of my payment form , and remove the stuff about the controller since it is indeed, not needed in the controller